# DBI handle sharing issues with DBD::MySQL in Apache, only on one server

Tags: mysql, apache, perl, fork, dbi

We have an application that runs in Apache with the prefork MPM and mod_perl2.  It uses DBD::mysql for database connections, and it has a lot of modules that initialize prepared statements when they are loaded, like so:

```
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect($connection_string, $user);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT column FROM table WHERE other_column = ?");

sub new {
    # ...
}
```

Some of these modules are loaded in startup.pl, which causes the db initialization code to run when the Apache control process is starting up. The $dbh is therefore shared to the forked processes.

We're trying to migrate this application to a newly-built server, and we're getting some really weird intermittent behavior, namely:

- Queries will sometimes return results that are clearly from another query
- We occasionally get "Lost connection to MySQL server during query"
- DBI trace shows a lot of "Handle is not in asynchronous mode error 2000 recorded" messages

Now, I understand that DBD::MySQL and the underlying C libraries don't support handles being shared to forked processes, and we need to fix our code so this doesn't happen.  But my question is: **Why don't we have problems in our current production environment**?  The new server is the same in every way I know to look at:

- Same Ubuntu version (12.04)
- Same Apache version (2.2)
- Same version of DBI (1.616) and DBD::mysql (4.020)
- Same Apache configuration and enabled modules
- Same MySQL client configuration
- Same version (50531) and compilation settings (specifically, enable-thread-safe-client) for MySQL client binaries
- Same code, including startup.pl and envvars
- Connecting to the same MySQL server

**What magic could there be in our production environment that is allowing our application to work correctly?**

Comment: What version of DBI and DBD::mysql are you running on each system? Do you have logging configured the same on both? (Maybe errors just aren't getting logged on one system, or they're going somewhere you don't expect.) Does the DBI trace show the asynchronous mode errors consistently, or intermittently? Did you do the trace on both systems?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - I've updated the question with DBI and DBD::mysql versions. To answer your other questions: Logging is configured the same on both systems. These errors actually surface in the application, not just in the logs, and they only happen on the affected system. I've only done a DBI trace on the affected system. In that trace, the "asynchronous mode" errors show up pretty consistently any time a statement is executed.

Comment: You failed to mention you're obviously using mod_perl. Is it the same version on both? Is the startup.pl the same on both? Is the environment the same?

Comment: @jcaron - The env vars and startup.pl are the same.  The versions of mod_perl2 are slightly different - 2.000005 in the "good" environment, 2.000008 in the "bad" environment.  I will see if there's a way I can test whether the lower version works correctly in the "bad" environment.